# ¿Cómo detectar posición actual y parar una animación en d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Tengo una aplicación web que usa [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) y la estoy actualizando para que use [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) en su lugar. Es un juego en el que uno de los elementos está animado y cae por la pantalla hasta que choca contra el "suelo" u otro elemento.

He conseguido crear la animación para que caiga haciendo que vaya de manera lineal desde la parte superior de la pantalla hasta la parte inferior así (ejemplo reducido):

```js
var wh = window.innerHeight - 40;

d3.select("#tile")
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .style("top", wh + "px")
  .ease("linear");
```

```css
#tile {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background:#336699;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="tile"></div>
```

Esto funciona perfectamente si no hay ningún otro elemento en el camino, pero si lo hubiera, me encuentro con dos problemas:

- Con jQuery uso un [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) con una función `step` en la que obtengo la posición actual del elemento y compruebo si ha habido colisiones con otros elementos. **¿Existe un equivalente a `step()` para `transition()` en d3.js?**
- Una vez detectada la colisión, **¿cómo puedo hacer que la animación se cancele y el elemento deje de moverse?** (algo así como el `stop()` en jQuery).

Para el segundo punto, he visto que puedo crear una transición vacía con duración 0 y eso solucionaría el problema, pero ¿hay algún método más directo?

Comment: Cree un [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965734/how-to-detect-current-elements-position-and-cancel-an-animation-in-d3-js) en StackOverflow en inglés.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el [cross-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965734/how-to-detect-current-elements-position-and-cancel-an-animation-in-d3-js) del sitio en inglés obtuve una respuesta de [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34965964/3695983) que contestaba las dos preguntas:

**¿Existe un equivalente a `step()` para `transition()` en d3.js?**

Sí. La idea sería crear una función `tween` propia y de esta manera tener control absoluto sobre la transición. En cada iteración se podría comprobar la posición del elemento y cancelar la animación si hubo una colisión.

**¿Cómo puedo hacer que la animación se cancele y el elemento deje de moverse?**

Como menciono en la pregunta, esto se haría añadiendo una transición vacía, sin necesidad de poner una duración de 0 milisegundos para esa transición.

---

Un ejemplo de cómo quedaría una vez aplicados los cambios (se considera que hay una colisión a mitad de pantalla y entonces se para la animación):

```js
var wh = window.innerHeight - 40;

d3.select("#tile")
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .ease("linear")
  .tween("caida", function() {
    var i = d3.interpolateNumber(0, wh);
    var self = d3.select(this);
    return function(t) {
      var hayColision = (t > 0.5); // condición de parada (mitad de pantalla para pruebas)
      if (hayColision) {
        self.transition(); // cancelar la transición
      } else {
        self.style("top", i(t) + "px");  // no hay colisión, continúa cayendo
      }
    };
});
```

```css
#tile {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background:#336699;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="tile"></div>
```